# Difficulties getting a pure sounding sine wave (currently getting a subtle frequency with it)

Tags: c, audio, sdl

I'm attempting to play a pure sine wave in SDL2, but I'm finding that I can't seem to get a completely pure tone. It sounds pretty close to a true sine wave, but there is a slight secondary frequency behind it that sounds closer to a square wave. I've recorded the sound and verified that it is indeed incorrect when playing through two sets of speakers on two different systems (compared to a pure sine wave)

I've tried quite a few things at this point, including implementing multiple sine waves from stack overflow, and attempting to adapt the code from Handmade Hero. But each time, the same problem crops up. My suspicion is that there's something wrong with the bit precision, an incorrect cast somewhere, or that it has something to do with the specific way that SDL audio works that I'm not navigating around properly

Here's the main audio callback function that I'm currently working with along with my most recent attempt at writing a sine wave to the buffer:

```cpp
#define Pi32 3.14159265359f
#define Tau32 (2.0f * Pi32)

void
AudioCallback(void* UserData, u8* Stream, int Length)
{
    audio_user_data* AudioUserData = (audio_user_data*)UserData;
    static u32 Count = 0;

    u16* SampleBuffer = (u16*)Stream;
    int SamplesToWrite = Length / AudioUserData->BytesPerSample;
    for(int SampleIndex = 0; SampleIndex < SamplesToWrite; SampleIndex++)
    {
        u16 ToneValue = round((AudioUserData->ToneVolume * sin(Tau32 * (f32)Count / (f32)AudioUserData->WavePeriod)));
        *SampleBuffer++ = ToneValue;
        *SampleBuffer++ = ToneValue;
        ++Count;
    }
}
```

I would be happy to provide more context if it might help

EDIT -- Additional Context:

```cpp
#include "x:\SDL2-2.0.10\include\SDL.h"

#define Pi32 3.14159265359f
#define Tau32 (2.0f * Pi32)

#define INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH (8*80)
#define INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT (8*60)

typedef struct audio_user_data audio_user_data;
struct audio_user_data
{
    int SamplesPerSecond;
    int BytesPerSample;
    int SampleIndex;
    int ToneHz;
    int ToneVolume;
    int WavePeriod;
    u32 FileLength;
    u16* BufferLocation;
};

void
AudioCallback(void* UserData, u8* Stream, int Length)
{
    audio_user_data* AudioUserData = (audio_user_data*)UserData;
    static u32 Count = 0;

    u16* SampleBuffer = (u16*)Stream;
    int SamplesToWrite = Length / AudioUserData->BytesPerSample;
    for(int SampleIndex = 0; SampleIndex < SamplesToWrite; SampleIndex++)
    {
        u16 ToneValue = (0.5f + (AudioUserData->ToneVolume * sin(Tau32 * Count / AudioUserData->WavePeriod)));
        *SampleBuffer++ = ToneValue;
        *SampleBuffer++ = ToneValue;
        ++Count;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO);

    SDL_Window* Window = SDL_CreateWindow("Spell Checker", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH*2, INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT*2, 0);
    SDL_Renderer* Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Window, 0, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    SDL_PixelFormat* Format = SDL_AllocFormat(SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888);
    SDL_Texture* Screen = SDL_CreateTexture(Renderer, Format->format, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    audio_user_data AudioUserData = {0};
    AudioUserData.SamplesPerSecond = 44100;
    AudioUserData.BytesPerSample = 2 * sizeof(int16);
    AudioUserData.SampleIndex = 0;
    AudioUserData.ToneVolume = 3000;
    AudioUserData.ToneHz = 440;
    AudioUserData.WavePeriod = AudioUserData.SamplesPerSecond / AudioUserData.ToneHz;

    SDL_AudioSpec Want, Have;
    SDL_AudioDeviceID AudioDeviceID;
    Want.freq = AudioUserData.SamplesPerSecond;
    Want.format = AUDIO_S16;
    Want.channels = 2;
    Want.samples = 4096;
    Want.callback = &AudioCallback;
    Want.userdata = &AudioUserData;
    AudioDeviceID = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(0, 0, &Want, &Have, 0);

    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(AudioDeviceID, 0); // Start playing

    u32* PixelMap = calloc(INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH * INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT, sizeof(PixelMap));

    int PixelMapLocation = 0;
    int Running = 1;
    while(Running)
    {

        SDL_Event Event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            if(Event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                Running = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Test colors
        PixelMapLocation = 0;
        for(int Row = 0; Row < INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH; ++Row)
        {
            for(int Col = 0; Col < INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT; ++Col)
            {
                PixelMap[PixelMapLocation++] = 0xFF00FF;
            }
        }
        for(int Row = 0; Row < INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH; ++Row)
        {
            for(int Col = 0; Col < INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT; ++Col)
            {
                PixelMap[PixelMapLocation++] = 0x00FFFF;
            }
        }

        SDL_UpdateTexture(Screen, 0, PixelMap, INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH * sizeof(PixelMap));
        SDL_RenderClear(Renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer, Screen, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

EDIT2:
I recorded the audio I'm hearing here (might need to turn the volume up to hear the problem):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V2IMhK2Zis&feature=youtu.be

I also ran a timing test, and got this back for the each run through of the AudioCallback function:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogn8u.jpg

EDIT3:
Oscilloscope readings --

My sine wave:
[image: Impure sine wave]

A pure sine wave:
[image: Pure sine wave]

(I can't see an appreciable difference, but maybe someone else can?) Edit: Oh wait, on the left side of the oscilloscope, there are clear differences between the two waveforms (though they don't appear in the main reading). Trying to figure out what the issue is -- at this point I am still unsure since I have tried several different algorithms

EDIT4:
Here's a picture of Want / Have to show that everything (other than size) is the same after calling SDL_OpenAudioDevice:

[image: Want vs Have]

EDIT5:
Problem (sort of) solved! Setting AudioUserData.SamplesPerSecond to 48000 resulted in a pure sounding sine wave. But the question still stands: why does it only work at 48000??

Comment: Reduce the amplitude?

Comment: round rather than truncate, ie add 0.5f before the cast to U16?

Comment: @MartinJames - No luck reducing the amplitude, unfortunately, but I added more context to the main post in case it has something to do with that

Comment: @dmuir - I added the rounding to the edit I just made to the first post. I'm still getting the same impure sine wave though

I added the main post with additional context, as it might have to do with how I'm setting up SDL or something like that

Comment: Can you record the output sound with another tool? Then you could look at the wave form to get an idea what can be wrong.

Comment: One thing you might want to try is timing how long it takes for your `AudioCallback` to run. When I was generating sinewave tones on a microcontroller (so probably different than your system) I found the `sin` was too slow to keep up, thus making sounds that were close to the right time but had that square-wave choppiness in them. Again, this was a 32Mhz processor so your setup is likely much faster but it did produce a result similar to what you describe.

Comment: @thebusybee I was able to record the audio (and I uploaded it to YouTube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V2IMhK2Zis&feature=youtu.be) However, I can't find a suitable analysis tool for this machine (Windows 10). I tried several, but they either only supported microphone recording, or had really poor resolutions

Comment: @Unn Hmm.. That's interesting. I do know that this machine has had audio latency issues in the past, but it has a 3.5Ghz i7 in it. I ran some tests and got these results: https://imgur.com/a/9pqCte0 That seems slow to me, but I've only been coding for like ~9 months, and I will readily admit that I don't know much about timing or optimization

Comment: Strongly suggest: 1) record the audio tone with an oscilloscope so you can see exactly the timing and etc of the audio output.  2) There are a LOT of implicit conversions in the posted code,  So suggest using a debugger to step through the code to see what is exactly being produced

Comment: @user3629249 I tried using several oscilloscopes earlier, but I switched to my Mac and finally found a usable one. I've updated the main post with picture comparisons. I've also stepped through the debugger quite a few times in this process. ToneValue is an unsigned int that moves in a sine-wave between its max value and its minimum value as far as I can tell. The conversion to unsigned does make it go from 0 - 5000 then from 0 to (wrapped around) 60537, but adding 5000 to the value (so it moves from 0 to 10,000) does not change the sound or fix the problem

Comment: the posted images are NOT of a sine wave.  Suggest you start with why the values are not of a sine wave

Comment: Does the pure sine wave sound correct to you when played through those speakers? Maybe it's just the fidelity of your speakers. (Also, what actually is your source for the "pure" sine wave?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, the "pure" sine wave does indeed sound correct on both sets of speakers, while my own sine wave sounds incorrect on both sets of speakers. Here is what I used for the pure sine wave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGXYFJmvIvk

Comment: Why aren't you checking `Have` and taking any differences (format, frequency) from `Want` into account in `AudioCallback()`?

Comment: @genpfault Hi again, and thanks! Now, rather than allowing any changes, I just set the last flag of `SDL_OpenAudioDevice` to 0 and verified that Want and Have are the same (in any way that I know how to handle). I've edited the main post to include a picture of this; note that size is the only difference (but I don't think I'm using that?) -- I will add code to take into account any changes later on

Comment: @Lo-Phi: Much better, thank you!